# How to build a tree-like array of unlimited nesting?

Tags: php, arrays

There are 2 arrays. The first array is the parents of the first level, and the second is the children (the parent is specified in the 'referer' key). How can they be hierarchically combined into a third one, provided that the nesting can be conditionally unlimited?

**Array 1 (first level parents):**

```
$array1 = [
    ['page'=>'1.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'3.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'6.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]]
];
```

**Array 2 (children):**

```
$array2 = [
    ['page'=>'666.ru', 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'66.ru'],
    ['page'=>'33.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'3.ru'],
    ['page'=>'66.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'6.ru']
];
```

**Array 3 (desired result):**

```
$array3 = [
    ['page'=>'1.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'3.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[
        ['page'=>'33.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'childs'=>[]],
    ]],
    ['page'=>'6.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[
        ['page'=>'66.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'childs'=>[
            ['page'=>'666.ru', 'title'=>'+', 'childs'=>[]]
        ]]
    ]]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create and operate on some intermediate data structures in order to build a tree from flat arrays. It's really just a few basic loops.

```php
<?php
$array1 = [
    ['page'=>'1.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'3.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'6.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]]
];

$array2 = [
    ['page'=>'666.ru', 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'66.ru'],
    ['page'=>'33.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'3.ru'],
    ['page'=>'66.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'6.ru']
];

// Create a map of the child records using the page value as the key
$childPageMap = [];
foreach($array2 as $currRow)
{
    // Everybody gets a child array
    $currRow['childs'] = [];
    $childPageMap[$currRow['page']] = $currRow;
}

// Populate the map
foreach($childPageMap as $currPage=>$currRow)
{
    $currParent = $currRow['referer'];
    
    /*
     * If we find a matching parent, add the current record to the children
     * and remove it from the top level
     */
    if(array_key_exists($currParent, $childPageMap))
    {
        $childPageMap[$currParent]['childs'] = $currRow;
        unset($childPageMap[$currPage]);
    }
}

// Create a map of the child branches using the referer value as the key
$childRefererMap = [];
foreach($childPageMap as $currRow)
{
    /*
     * There may be multiple branches with the same parent,
     * so each entry in the map should be an array
     */
    $childRefererMap[$currRow['referer']][] = $currRow;
}

// Iterate through the parents, pulling the child branches from the childReferer map
array_walk( $array1, function(&$currRow, $key, $childRefererMap)
{
    // If we find an entry in the childRefererMap, merge the branches into our children
    if(array_key_exists($currRow['page'], $childRefererMap))
    {
        $currRow['childs'] = array_merge($currRow['childs'], $childRefererMap[$currRow['page']]);
    }
}, $childRefererMap);

print_r($array1);
```